# How should I list multiple pick-ups of the same published media interviews on a CV?

Tags: cv

I am updating a physician's CV where there are many instances where a printed or online interview he did was picked up and published by several different (unrelated) publications. I am unable to find the best way to show these as consolidated listings, rather than repeating them as individual listings. Is there an approved MLA or another gold-standard format that I can use? Thanks for your help.

Randi Pincus

Comment: Why would anyone care if the same interview was republished in multiple places? That's how wires work